# array of arrays visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a module for capture Attlogs from a ZKSoftware Fingerprint Biometric and send it to MySQL database using the SDK that came with the CD, so far I manage to connect successfully to the clock, display the logs on a listview, but I got stuck pushing the values on a multidimensional array, i'm sure it's a matter of declaration but I better ask for help... the code is as follows:

```
Dim thisLog(1) As String
Dim allLogs()() As String = New String()() {}
```

afterwards where the iteration (i) load the Attlogs in the listview I got:

```
            thisLog = {sdwEnrollNumber, idwYear.ToString() & "-" + idwMonth.ToString() & "-" & idwDay.ToString() & " " & idwHour.ToString() & ":" & idwMinute.ToString() & ":" & idwSecond.ToString()}
            allLogs(i) = {thisLog(0), thisLog(1)}
```

The error I'm getting is related to the size of the array, so the question can be resumed in how can I create a rectangular array (2)(n) with every row of the captured data. Thanks in advance

Comment: From the looks for this, you really want a `List(Of String)`, `List(Of String())`, or `List(Of List(Of String))` instead of `String()()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest you create a class to store the data in. Have a List(Of LogEntry) afterward. This would make your code a lot easier to read.

```
Class LogEntry

    Public Property EnrollNumber As String
    Public Property EntryDate As DateTime

    Public Sub New(ByVal enrollNumber As String, ByVal entryDate As DateTime)

        Me.EnrollNumber = enrollNumber
        Me.EntryDate = entryDate

    End Sub

End Class
```

For adding a new record, you just need to create an instance of that class and add it to the list.

```
    Dim allLogs As New List(Of LogEntry)

    allLogs.Add(New LogEntry(sdwEnrollNumber, New DateTime(idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond)))
```

Since you'll now have a valid date instead of a concatenation of string, it'll be easy to do manipulation afterward.

```
    Console.WriteLine(allLogs(0).EnrollNumber)
    Console.WriteLine(allLogs(0).EntryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I create a rectangular array (2)(n) with every row of the captured data?

Use a List:

```
Dim allLogs As New List(Of String())()

allLogs.Add(New String(1) {sdwEnrollNumber, _
     String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", _
     idwYear, idwMonth, idwDay, idwHour, idwMinute, idwSecond)} )
```

I might also use the [appropriate DateTime constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx) and [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format that 2nd part, depending on how you get those `idw` variables in the first place.

Comment: thanks, I will format the DateTime this way, the idw variables comes from the SDK function libs, each one is declared as Integer